# How to drag an image to move it smoothly on screen, using jquery in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a project where we can move an image like in google map,, it works perfectly in crome,ff and above ie9, but when i checked in ie8 the image is not moving smoothly,it takes a 2 to 3 sec of time to move.

```
/* Map dragging */
    var previousX;
    var previousY;
    var previousLeft;
    var previousTop;
    var cids = self.data.cuLocation;
    var lumids = self.data.lumLocation;
   $('#MapView img').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
    $("#MapView img").mousedown(function(e) {
      //console.log("mousedown");

        e.preventDefault();
        drag.state = true;
        previousX = e.originalEvent.clientX;
        previousY = e.originalEvent.clientY;
        previousLeft = $("#MapView img").position().left;
        previousTop = $("#MapView img").position().top;

    });
    $("#MapView img").mousemove(function(e) {
         var old_pos = self.getPosition();
        if (drag.state) {
            e.preventDefault();
            drag.x = e.originalEvent.clientX - previousX;
            drag.y = e.originalEvent.clientY - previousY;

            var cur_position = $("#MapView img").position();
            var new_left = cur_position.left + drag.x;
            var new_top = cur_position.top + drag.y;
            previousX = e.originalEvent.clientX;
            previousY = e.originalEvent.clientY;
        }

    });
     $("#MapView img").mouseleave(function(e) {
      //console.log("mouseleave");
        drag.state = false;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
       // alert("mouseup");
        drag.state = false;
        });
```

Comment: using draggable() is good, but the problem is i dont want to show the whitespace,i have to limit the whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Link for your better understanding in Draggable event so than you can use it to Drag your Image wherever you want.
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

and for Drap & Drop of one element onto other element ::
 http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to